# How does a friendly, personal feeling affect a website or web app user's experience?

Tags: wording

I am under the impression that if you try to make a "human" feel to a particular website or app, that a user will find it easier to use.

After a short discussion with a colleague, I realize this may not be the consensus among the UX community.

By human, I mean stuff like:

- Instead of "Your transaction was successful.", saying "Awesome! Everything worked."
- Instead of showing check boxes and warning signs, stuff like thumbs up and thumbs down

I was wondering what ux.stackexchange thought about this.

**Let's try to keep this as objective as possible. Try to include examples from reputable sources.**

Comment: This question is too broad to answer here.  (I've read two books on the topic.)  Check out [*Seductive Interaction Design*](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/577893824) by Stephen P Anderson and [*Designing for Emotion*](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/515160249) by Aarron Walter

Comment: Yes this is too broad a question for a Q&A site I'm afraid. It's more of a discussion topic than an answerable question. Try visiting the [chat] to see what people think there but it doesn't really dot with this site as an answerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are talking about the tone of the website/application. Few reasons why you would like to give your product a tone/personality are:

- In a crowded market, personality helps distinguish you from competitors.
- Personality elicits an emotional response from the audience that encourages long-term memory of your brand.
- Personality attracts those who get you and deters those who don’t.
- Personality impassions users, who will become your most powerful marketing channel.

An interesting article in Smashing UX mag explaining how you can find the tone for your product. [Finding your tone of voice](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/21/finding-tone-voice/)

The use of thumbs up/down instead of other methods is just a matter of consistency of the tone. For a friendly tone you might use thumbs up, in a sports website, you might use some other metaphor.

Comment: Thank you, this article is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)